Grafana and Azure Elasticsearch service data source: open port 9200
I am setting up Elasticsearch data source in Grafana. I am following the instructions
The Elasticsearch is running in Azure as Service (Elastic Observability (Elasticsearch) - An Azure Native ISV Service). When I set the URL in the data source configuration, I use the one provided in Azure and the 9200 port
Grafana
but I cannot connect
I have tested if the port 9200 is open with
test-NetConnection xxx.es.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com -Port 9200
WARNING: TCP connect to (20.xxx.xxx.29 : 9200) failed

ComputerName           : xxxx.es.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com
RemoteAddress          : 20.xxx.xxx.29
RemotePort             : 9200
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet 4
SourceAddress          : 10.xx.xxx.59
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 20 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False

and actually, the port is not open. Then I read on internet that we need to open it changing the Elasticsearch setting with network.host=0.0.0.0.
So I thought maybe I need to open the port 9200 on the Azure Elasticsearch service.
Then I tried to do it in the Azure Elasticsearch portal setting network.host=0.0.0.0and get
Save configuration settings?
Your changes cannot be applied

Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed
Set network.host to 0.0.0.0
No significant Kibana configuration changes
No significant APM configuration changes
No significant Integrations Server configuration changes
No significant Enterprise Search configuration changes

and it seems I cannot change the setting even it I am the administrator of the Elasticsearch service.
So, my questions are:

Is it possible use the Azure Elasticsearch service as Grafana data source?
if yes to the 1. how can I open the port 9200 of the Azure Elasticsearch service to be able to set it as data source in Grafana?

Please let me know if you can help
Thanks
Alberto

I figured out how to set it up and post it here for reference.

we need to use the URL https:\xxx.es.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243 and not the one with Port 9200 since we need https and not http. See documentation

Create a user in the Elasticsearch portal
user

Configure Grafana with URL and basic authentication


grafana_setup
And the connection is working
connection_ok
Hope this will help someone else.
